# how to check if $1 and $2 are null?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am running some script which passing the string argument and I want to do if else statement shown as below:

```bsh
if [ $1 != '' ] && [ $2 != '' ]
then 
    do something.....
```

but it shown `Error too many argument`. Why?

Comment: You should provide 1. the command which you call the script and 2. the full output.

Comment: You should use `[[ ]]`. Otherwise you have to quote your variables.

Comment: If $1 didn't exist then $2 would become $1 which makes the test of $1 and $2 both being null seem irrelevant.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  Not necessarily irrelevant - in some cases you want to ensure there's actually something instead of blank or null string in arguments. `$1` could be unset or set to null string by user of the script. Consider this sequence of command: `$ set '' bar` then `echo "x${1}x"；` Both variables are set, but one of them is null.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try using the -z test:

```
if [ -z "$1" ] && [ -z "$2" ]
```

From man `bash`:

```
-z string
   True if the length of string is zero.
```

Comment: When writing portable shell scripts, this flag should be used with care, since on certain commercial Unixes this flag is faulty. See my answer for linked sources.

Answer (score 20):

Since this is tagged `bash`, I recommend that one use the [extended test construct (`[[...]]`)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS), and forget the quotes:

```
if [[ -z $1 && -z $2 ]]; then
...
```

Unless you are going for `sh`/POSIX compatibility, there is no reason not to use `[[ ]]`.

Answer (score 6):

The following also works,

```
if [ "$1" == "" && "$2" == ""]; then
    echo NULL
fi
```

Comment: The `&&` and other logical command separators are not allowed in the classic `test`. You have to use other test constructs instead (like `-a`, I think)

Answer (score 4):

<sub>For the old version of the answer, see the second portion of this answer. If you want to know about details, read on</sub>

#### The cause of issue

In the question itself, it is reported that OP sees `too many arguments error`, which when tested in `bash` doesn't seem to be the case:

```
$ [ $1 != '' ] && [ $2 != '' ]
bash: [: !=: unary operator expected
```

With `/bin/sh` which is actually symlinked to `/bin/dash` on Ubuntu, error reported as follows:

```
$ sh
$ [ $1 != '' ] && [ $2 != '' ]
sh: 1: [: !=: unexpected operator
```

And the standalone `/bin/test` also :

```
$ /usr/bin/test $1 != ''  
/usr/bin/test: missing argument after ‘’
```

Sidenote: If you're wondering what is `/usr/bin/test` and why I'm using `bash` and `sh`, then you should know that `[` is alias for `test` command, which also exists as standalone executable or more commonly - as shell built-in which is what each shell will use first. As for `if` statements, they operate on exit statues of commands, hence why `[` and `test` are commands, with everything else being arguments to that commands - improper order of those command-line args leads to errors.

Back to the topic: it's unclear how OP got the unrelated error. However, in all 3 cases the issue is the same - unset variable will be treated as empty, thus what the shell sees with  these unquoted variables is

```
[ != '' ]
```

which breaks syntax which `test` understands. Remember what I said about improper order of command-line arguments ? Hence why quoting is important. Let's enable diagnostic output and see what shell executes:

```
$ set -x
# throws error
$ [ $1 != '' ] && [ $2 != '' ] 
+ '[' '!=' '' ']'
bash: [: !=: unary operator expected
# no error
$ [ "$1" != '' ] && [ "$2" != '' ] || echo null vars
+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+ echo null vars
null vars
```

---

#### Better way to test unset variables

A very frequent approach that you see around is this:

```
 if [ "x$var1" == "x"  ] && [ "x$var2" == "x"  ];                                                                
 then
     echo "both variables are null"
 fi
```

To quote [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles):

> In [ "x$1" = "x" ], the x prefix ensures that x"$1" cannot possibly look like an operator, and so the only way the shell can parse this test is by treating = as a binary operator.

Presumably, this should be fairly portable since I've seen these in `/bin/sh` scripts. It also can be combined as in

```
if [ "x${var1}${var2}" == "x" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Of course we could use `-z` flag, however according to research in some shells, particularly ksh88 (according to [Stephane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32180/testing-if-a-variable-is-empty-in-a-shell-script#comment78383_32230)), this flag is faulty.

#### See also

- [Performance of test command in various shell](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/test/)
- [Bash operators `\[` vs `\[\[` vs `((`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs)

Comment: This should be the right answer, this approach resolves two variables conditions at the same time. Excellent details, and thanks I learned something

Answer (score 3):

I think the title of the post is not accurate, as the intention in the message was to check if $1 and $2 are not null.
The given example was just missing double quotes in $1 and $2 to work. 
Variables must be double quoted to be expanded when comparing strings.
But, to check if $1 and $2 exist is the same as check if $2 exist, as it can't exist if $1 doesn't. 
The 'if' command is also not needed in this case, as 'test' returns true/false and uses '&&' as 'then' if return is 0/true:

```
[ "$2" != '' ] && commands...
```

Simpler, with -n (nonzero):

```
[ -n "$2" ] && commands...
```

To "check if $1 and $2 are null" would be the same as check if there is no parameter:

```
[ $# -eq 0 ] && commands...
```